# EF Core multiple entities to one table with foreign key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have created this hierarchical database:

[image]

where every person has a manager, and a manager can have multiple employees.

I then created these C# objects:

[image]

[image]

I added them to the modelbuilder like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(p =>
        {
            p.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
            p.Property(e => e.Name).HasColumnName("Name");

            p.HasOne(e => e.Manager).WithMany(e => e.Employees).HasForeignKey(e => e.ManagerId);
        });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Manager>(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("Persons");
            m.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
            m.Property(e => e.Name).HasColumnName("Name");

            m.HasMany(x => x.Employees).WithOne().HasForeignKey(p => p.Id);
        });
}
```

But the results I get are:

[image]

Expected is that Mary has employees Catherine and Anna as shown in the database screenshots.

What am I doing wrong?

I get an error on changing the foreign key property in the manager modelbuilder for example:

> Cannot use table 'Persons' for entity type 'Person' since it is being used for entity type 'Manager' and potentially other entity types, but there is no linking relationship. Add a foreign key to 'Person' on the primary key properties and pointing to the primary key on another entity type mapped to 'Persons'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As entities in EF Core is abstractions of tables, you can't map multiple entities to single table. It may seem that your table has multiple entities but it is not. What it actually indicating is your table is a **self referential** table/entity.

Your entity should look like:

```
public class Person {
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}

   public int? ManagerId {get; set;}
   public Person? Manager {get; set;}
}
```

Also, you don't need the *managerName* column in your table since it is a navigation property.

EF Core Query would be like:

```
var person = _context.Persons.Include(p=>p.Manager)....
```

Then you can get the manager name as:

```
var managerName = person.Manager.Name;
```

To get the managed persons by the above person:

```
var managedPeoples = _context.Persons.Where(p=> p.ManagerId == person.Id);
```

No additional configuration needed in *OnModelCreating* unless you want to rename your table/column names or add additional index/constraints.

Comment: Please note: It is generally possible to map multiple entities to one table.

Comment: As far as I know, EF Core doesn't allow mapping of more than one entity to the same table in the same DbContext. You can always manually do that though. But I wonder why anybody would do that?

Comment: I am linking the docs for reference: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/table-splitting
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance

Comment: If you could edit you first sentence I would have nothing to complain :)

Comment: Please suggest corrections or edit.

Comment: I want to do that because the database already exists and doesn't meet the OOP principles the way it is designed. I think because declarative and imperative programming have two separate approaches. 
So in order to develop SOLID and avoid treating 'symptoms' so to say, I tried to model the database as I'd see fit. Does that make sense?